# How to get ar on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, installation, msys2

I'm trying to use cabal on windows (installed using chocolatey), and it is looking for "ar", which is a GNU utility, and I have no idea how to install that.

```
# In powershell or git bash
git clone https://github.com/haskell/text
cd text
cabal build --with-gcc=msys2
```

Error message excerpt (and yes I am intentionally using 8.2.2, `-w ghc-8.2.2`):

```
Failed to build call-stack-0.4.0.
Build log (
C:\cabal\logs\ghc-8.2.2\call-stack-0.4.0-99b0801375eba6b85bc1a82c10630c85f20debfa.log
):
Preprocessing library for call-stack-0.4.0..
Building library for call-stack-0.4.0..
[1 of 3] Compiling Data.SrcLoc      ( src\Data\SrcLoc.hs, dist\build\Data\SrcLoc.o )
[2 of 3] Compiling Data.CallStack   ( src\Data\CallStack.hs, dist\build\Data\CallStack.o )
[3 of 3] Compiling Paths_call_stack ( dist\build\autogen\Paths_call_stack.hs, dist\build\Paths_call_stack.o )
cabal.exe: The program 'ar' is required but it could not be found.



(and a whole lot more identical errors for other packages)
```

Comment: I have tried ghcup (before chocolatey in fact), identical problem. Stuff is getting installed, but not found. It didn't find a C compiler either, which is why I am passing the `--with-gcc` option, but that might be a symptom of the same configuration issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to install GCC, which, as far as I can tell by looking at the MSYS2 setup on my machine, doesn't seem to come with the initial MSYS2 install. That would be done through pacman, on the MSYS shell (see [the MSYS2 wiki](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-introduction/) for a primer on the MSYS2 shells and subsystems):

```sh
# Updates the package database and the currently installed packages.
# If the shell closes at the end of the update, reopen it and rerun.
pacman -Syu
# Installs gcc.
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

In particular, `ar` is installed as part of `mingw-w64-x86_64-binutils`, which is a dependency of `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`.

Additional notes:

- GCC will be installed to `mingw64\bin` under your MSYS2 root. You might want to add that location to your PATH.
- [As you found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70819070/how-to-get-ar-on-windows/70823358?noredirect=1#comment125206419_70823358), if you are managing the tools through Chocolatey, `choco install mingw` will set up the basic MinGW development toolchain, which includes GCC.

Comment: A few things: I'm wary of adding `usr/bin` to PATH, since the names of executable can overlap with `mingw64/bin`. (At least `usr/bin` should be later in PATH.). And `pacman -Syu` sometimes likes to close the MSYS2 shell - then it needs to be called again to finish the update.

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Using chocolatey, an equivalent invocation is `choco install mingw`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Noted, thanks. I have edited the answer to mention the recommended order.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia Thanks, I have added that to the answer. (Lately I have been trying to figure out how to properly manage a GHCup + MSYS2 environment without using Chocolatey, so I ended up overlooking the Chocolatey side of your question at first.)